# Does jQuery animate use css3 transitions on modern browsers?

Tags: jquery, css, animation, jquery-animate, css-transitions

I am taking about version 1.8+.

Since css transitions are hardware accelerated, I was wondering if behind the scenes jQuery's animate function relied on css3 transitions (for modern browsers).

I didn't see any mention of this on animate docs http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. It rapidly changes the value of inline style attributes, step-by-step, to give the impression of animation.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery does not yet use CSS 3 probably due to minor issues between browsers in how they implement special use cases. So far not everything is consistent, and sometimes there are bugs that are very difficult to work around.

There are however plugins such as jQuery Transit that do use CSS 3 animations/transitions/etc. With Transit, you can fall-back to using `.animate()` like so:

```
// Delegate .transition() calls to .animate()
// if the browser can't do CSS transitions.
if (!$.support.transition)
  $.fn.transition = $.fn.animate;
```

http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/

Comment: +1 for the plugin. But I have to disagree with your statement about the issues between browsers; jQuery's main goal is to remove boilerplate code in cross-browser development, so I believe that should be another reason for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can see from the [source](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js) that it's not using any CSS3 (yet) for the animations.  (To see the animation code, search for "function Animation".)

Comment: any reason why the optimization is not there for modern browsers?

Answer (score 0):

No [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) doesn't use css transions but [Zepto](http://zeptojs.com/) (jQuery-compatible) uses CSS transitions for all of its animations and perform better than [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).